# TypeError: invalid type promotion xarray spatial mean

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to calculate a meridional [cosine weighted mean](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/area_weighted_temperature.html) of a sub-region and timeslice of a netcdf dataset, here is my code,

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

min_lat=2
max_lat=9
datestr="2017-03-10"

olrfile="olr-daily_v01r02_20170101_20171231.nc"
ds=xr.open_dataset(olrfile)
olr=ds.sel(lat=slice(min_lat,max_lat),time=datestr)
weights=np.cos(np.deg2rad(ds.lat))
olrw=olr.weighted(weights)
olrm=olrw.mean(dim=('lat'))
```

The final mean statement falls over with the error

```
File "/afs/ictp/home/t/tompkins/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.py", line 1350, in einsum
    return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

and I have no idea what is wrong...  I know I can do this with `cdo`, but I thought I would try to do it inline in `xarray` for speed.

[The link to the netcdf file dir is here.](http://clima-dods.ictp.it/Users/tompkins/so/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your current code is calculating the mean for all xarray variables. As more of a CDO user personally, I get confused by xarray setting bnds to variables. In this case it has time_bnds as a variable, and in your code it is trying to calculate the mean for that variable, but it's not working because (I think) there is no lat dimension for it.

You would just need to select the olr variable before calculating the weighting.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

min_lat=2
max_lat=9
datestr="2017-03-10"

olrfile="olr-daily_v01r02_20170101_20171231.nc"
ds=xr.open_dataset(olrfile)
olr=ds["olr"].sel(lat=slice(min_lat,max_lat),time=datestr)
weights=np.cos(np.deg2rad(ds.lat))
olrw=olr.weighted(weights)
olrm=olrw.mean(dim=('lat'))
```